# Solving Laplace's equation on an infinite strip

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

I have come across (and indeed, solved) variations of this problem on a *finite* strip, but not for an infinite strip as in my version of the problem. It is the standard two-dimensional Laplace's equation, with

$$u(a, y) = V,\,\,\,\, -\infty < y < +\infty$$
$$U(-a, y) = -V,\,\,\,\, -\infty < y < +\infty$$
$$\lim_{y \to +\infty}u_y(x, y) = 0,\,\,\,\, -a < x < a$$
$$\lim_{y \to -\infty}u_y(x, y) = 0,\,\,\,\, -a < x < a$$
Now, we are to solve this using separation of variables. My method therefore entails solving the second order ODE's given by
$$X''(x) - \sqrt{\lambda}X(x) = Y''(y) + \sqrt{\lambda}Y(y) = 0$$
At this point, I assume that the ODE in $X(x)$ is solved by an equation of the form
$$X(x) = C_1\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x) + C_2\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x)$$
Then applying the boundary conditions I get that
$$X(a) = C_1\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}a) + C_2\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}a) = V$$
and
$$X(-a)= C_1\sin(-\sqrt{\lambda}a) + C_2\cos(-\sqrt{\lambda}a)= -V$$
But I can exploit the fact that cosine and sine functions are symmetric, and re-phrase $X(-a)$ in the following way:
$$X(-a) = -C_1\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}a) + C_2\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}a) = -V$$
Then taking the difference of these equations I can conveniently note that
$$2C_2\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}a) = 0$$
from which I can solve
$$\sqrt{\lambda}a = \frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}$$
and hence
$$\lambda = \frac{(2n+1)^2\pi^2}{4a^2}$$
I wonder how to proceed, though? Those conditions that $Y'(y)$ must vanish as $y \to \infty$ seem to suggest a negative exponential for $Y(y)$, but I cannot seem to find one that works.

Comment: Are we talking about Laplace's equation $\nabla^2 V = 0$ wherein $V$ is the potential?

Comment: Unsure about the potential, but yes, standard $u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 0$

Comment: What do you think is going to be the value of $u(x,0)$?